# How can I attach a PCB patch antenna with microstrip feed to coax cable without soldering

Tags: connector, antenna, coax, microstrip, hf

I designed a patch antenna on a 1.5 mm thick substrate for 7 GHz. It has to be connected to a semi rigid coax cable. Due to the application it is meant for, I can not solder a SMA connector or the cable to the antenna. Conductive glues are also not an option.  I thought of a mechanical connection, but I could not find any. Has anyone had a similar problem before or knows about only mechanical connections that could fit for this problem?

Comment: Might pogo pins be an option?  Why can’t you use a connector - knowing this might make it easier to answer the question.

Comment: The antenna is going to be used in very low vacuum (artificial) and at high temperatures. Pogo pins might be an option

Comment: Braze or tack weld?

Comment: Could you create a small stackup of PCBs, milled with slots so they clamp against the outer and inner conductors of the cable, then tighten it all down with bolts and nuts?

Comment: Possibly spot weld

Comment: I don't think you're going to find anything off-the-shelf.  You're probably going to have to engineer a solution, working in conjunction with a reputable microwave cable/interconnect company, like GORE.  It won't be cheap.

Comment: Thank you all very much for the comments! I am going to try spot weld and let you know the result!

Comment: I wonder if pogo pins would either seize under vacuum, or the lubricant within outgasses interminably? Also, is it possible to arrange a microwave-transparent (plastic, glass, crystal, etc.) window to beam microwaves into the experiment from the outside? (Maybe even just into a waveguide, and onward to the patch antenna. Maybe this doesn't solve the bonding issues after all. Just a thought.)

Comment: Lubricants are available that do not out-gas, and are used on moving mechanisms destined for space.  I'm sure they're not cheap.  Unfortunately, OP has not given us any information on his cost target.